# Database.EnsureCreated not working if some of tables are already created

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

1. First step: set up empty database:
   [Empty DB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cPM9.png)
2. Setup all contexts.

   ```
   accessTokenContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
   userContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
   userGroupContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
   permissionContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
   roleContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
   ```

   All code: https://pastebin.com/DZVKnGx9
3. After starting API and making first request:
   [DB After Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIdWc.png)
4. It created only some of tables.

I expected for it to create all tables. However it created only 4.

Comment: I might be missing something but why are you creating a context for each type?

Comment: I have couple of managers that are divided to work only with their objects like User, UserCredential and so on.

Comment: Each time you call `EnsureCreated` the db gets wiped. You are much better off using a single context and using something else to authorize business rules like that.

Comment: Try Dispose context before created another one.

Answer (score 0):

You used the same DataBase (connectionString) for all DbContext. But  `EnsureCreated()` is simply check if DataBase not exist, it will create. So after the 1st `accessTokenContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` It will recognized as the Database has exist, so won't create anymore. (There could be some delay situation here).

So you couldn't use `EnsureCreated()` for multiple context in same DataBase. Instead, you could try following workaround.

```
accessTokenContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

try
{
    RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator2 = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)accessTokenContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
    databaseCreator2.EnsureCreated();
}
catch { }
try
{
    RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator3 = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)userGroupContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
    databaseCreator3.CreateTables();
}
catch { }
try
{
    RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator4 = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)permissionContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
    databaseCreator4.CreateTables();
}
catch { }
try
{
    RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator5 = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)roleContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
    databaseCreator5.CreateTables();
}
catch { }
```

Explain: "RelationalDatabaseCreator" only work for existing database so use "EnsureCreated" to make sure database exists. And  "RelationalDatabaseCreator" will have exception when table already exists so put them in the "try catch"